# CSS 1px jump i can't figure out for life of me

Tags: css

I'm using "Chosen" special input box for the "Project Type" input box on my form.

You can view here http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Here's my page below. You'll notice name, email, phone etc are all standard input boxes... but when you get to project type it all works perfectly but when you click ON one of the selections.. it still works fine. Look very closely when you click OFF the input box after you delete one of the options that you choose (off to the right of the page for instance to lose focus), and youll see everything below it including the footer.. input boxes below it.. submit button etc all shift 1px. Just play with it for a minute if that wasnt a good explanation and you'll see it shifting

I can't figure how what property this is.. the only thing I changed was padding: 5px to padding 6px on the input inside the div so it would match the rest of the input boxes..

http://eastcoastefx.vaesite.com/contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this in chrome only.

your div `id="sel1DT_chzn"` grows by 1 pixel when something is selected.

set its height to `33px`

```
<div id="sel1DT_chzn" class="chzn-container  chzn-container-multi" 
    style="width: 348px; height:  33px;"> ....
```

Comment: out of all the replies this was the only one that worked, however the problem is when you add a lot of tags (so it fills up more than one line) it stays like that and doesnt move the rest of the elements down like it should?

Comment: Maybe min-height? or overflow: auto? It really depends on your target browsers and your desired look.

Comment: Or take @imsky's suggestiong and change the `line-height: 12px` for `chzn-container-multi .chzn-choices .search-choice` line 172 . Also you should set your all your inputs to be the same height by default. Chrome dev tools show the other inputs as `30px` high.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fix:

chosen.css, selector at line 172:
line-height:12px

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ".chzn-container-active .chzn-choices .search-choice" aka the project item (Branding, Web Development etc..) has a height of 31px (including padding, margin and border) while it's container is only 30px in height. So it can be no higher than 29px, or else it would expand its container like it's doing now.

What I did to solve it in my browser is subtract 1px of the top margin and 1px of the bottom margin. But it's up to you how to do it.

Comment: can you tell me the exact line number? I removed 1px from a few different things and it made it worse? Thanks!